# SQL Server Query select case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to select different `ItemID` on different two cases.

In the first case I am selecting the `ItemID = @OrgID` that is the organisation parent because these doesn't have the `ParentOrganisationId` (is null) -- then this case work fine.

I have problem in the second case where I am checking if it is a branch then take with the subquery the `ParentOrganisationId` to bring = ItemID in the first where condition. This second case get null value.

```
Declare @OrgID int
Set @OrgID = 91702 --- 91702(Branch Organisation), 83279(Parent Organisation)

select ItemID 
FROM Organisations 
where ItemID = case
                  when ParentOrganisationId is null 
                    then @OrgID --case without branches
                  when ParentOrganisationId is not null 
                    then (select ParentOrganisationId 
                          from Organisations 
                          where ItemID = @OrgID) --case with branches
               end
```

Comment: put that in else part of first case statement

Comment: Also with else in the first case gets null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't next query work for you?

```
select coalesce(ParentOrganisationId, ItemId) as ItemID
from Organisations
where ItemID = @OrdID
```

Comment: Yes the coalesce method work fine but I can not use this method in my solution for different reasons, sorry.

Comment: Ok so it seems work fine, thanks for your help!
`Declare @OrgID int
Declare @OrgFinalID int
Set @OrgID = 91702 ---91703, 91702, 83279

select @OrgFinalID = 
case
when ParentOrganisationId is null then ItemID
else ParentOrganisationId
end
from T2U_Organisations
where ItemID = @OrgID`

Answer (score 4):

`case` statement returns a scalar expression, not a list.  Remove the `case` and express the logic using basic boolean operators:

```
select ItemID 
FROM Organisations
where (ParentOrganisationId is null and ItemID = @OrgID) or
      (ParentOrganisationId is not null and
       ItemID in (select ParentOrganisationId from Organisations where ItemID = @OrgID)
      );
```

Comment: I noted that ParentOrganisationId was nvarchar so I put in in cast but doesn't work yet, the result is null in the ParentOrganisationId not null:
`select ItemID 
FROM Organisations
where (ParentOrganisationId is null and ItemID = @OrgID) or
      (ParentOrganisationId is not null and
       ItemID in (select CAST(ParentOrganisationId AS INT) from Organisations where ItemID = @OrgID)
      );`